# Capture Desktop screen from Progressive Web APP

Tags: web, progressive-web-apps

We want to capture the desktop screen of a student from a progressive web application (PWA) for an Online Exam. We need to know whether it is possible to capture desktop screen from a web application? We have googled so much but couldn’t found a proper solution. Any help would be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the content OUTSIDE of your PWA? I have never seen that possibility. It is a massive security issue that would allow someone to capture private/personal information. Looks like there is draft here: https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-capture/

Comment: then how google hangouts captures desktop screen?